# how to make sure the data imported using sqoop follows the same row order in hive as in mysql table

Tags: sqoop

How to make sure the data imported using sqoop follows the same row order in hive as in mysql table?

`mysql> select * from customer;
+------+--------+------+--------+
| id   | name   | age  | salary |
+------+--------+------+--------+
| 1    | John   | 30   |  80000 |
| 2    | Kevin  | 33   |  84000 |
| 3    | Mark   | 28   |  90000 |
| 4    | Jenna  | 34   |  93000 |
| 5    | Robert | 32   | 100000 |
| 6    | Zoya   | 40   |  60000 |
| 7    | Sam    | 37   |  75000 |
| 8    | George | 31   |  67000 |
| 9    | Peter  | 23   |  70000 |
| 19   | Alex   | 26   |  74000 |
+------+--------+------+-----`

I want after the table has been imported. It follows the same order in hive too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While importing the tables into the hive using Apache Sqoop, by default it is in the same order but to be double sure, you can do one thing, if your MySQL table has the primary key then create hive table manually with same Schema and primary key and write import statement without --create-hive-table argument.

This way it will make sure that data will be in the same order as MySQL table